# How to disable Edit control's focus on Dialog first launch?

Tags: c++, winapi, focus, controls, edit

Hello everybody reading this. Thanks in advance for your time.

One thing before question: I DO NOT use neither MFC nor Windows Forms, just WinApi in C++.

Well, I am making a polynomial calculator in Visual C++. I added a Dialog to it, which was created in resources (`.rc` file) using drag'n'drop method. I suppose there would be no such a problem if i created my Dialog with `CreateWindowEx` (but I don't want to).

My Dialog has a few of Edit Controls. Everything is fine except that when the Dialog is launched, **one of Edit controls takes focus** to be ready to take keyboard input.

I have included management of `EN_KILLFOCUS` (Edit sends it to parent when loses focus due to selecting another control).

Here I read from control to `wstring` (string of wide characters - `_UNICODE` is defined), use some kind of parser to verify this `wstring` and remove bad characters, and then put correct string into the same edit control. It works fine, but here is **the source of my problem**:

When there was no input, parser returns `string "0"` (not the `NULL`, string is just set to "0"), as if control had focus and then lost it even before I clicked anything in Dialog.

Due to that, and **something else** (this is what I have to figure out), at the Dialog launch parser puts this `string "0"` to edit.

I want to make my edit not be able to take input from keyboard until i click one of the Edits (including this one).
If it is not possible, I want to clear the whole text at the beginning of dialog (being able to take input is not a problem, I just want to prevent parser from entering `string "0"` at the beginning)
My code:

In DlgProc I have:

```
//up here is switch to manage all controls
    case MyEditID:                // here is ID of one of my edits from resources
        switch (HIWORD(wParam))
        {
        case EN_KILLFOCUS:        // edit lost focus - another control selected

            if (LOWORD(wParam)==MyEditID)  //necessary to determine if
                                          // one of allowed Edits sent this message
                                          // because I have also other Edits
            {
                GetDlgItemText(hPanel, LOWORD(wParam), MyTempWcharArray, 100);
                MyTempString.assign(MyTempWcharArray);

                w1 = polynomial(MyTempWcharArray); // parser takes the string
                     // and removes bad chars in constructor
                     // polynomial is my class - you don't have to care of it
                     // w1 is declared before as object of polynomial class

                MyTempString = w1.ConversionToString();
                SetDlgItemText(hDialog, LOWORD(wParam), sw1);
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
```

does it matter what integer number is set to Edit's ID?

I know `SetFocus()`, and `WM_SETFOCUS` message. In this case I just can't get this working.

If i haven't included something important to make you see my point please let me know. I'm sorry I'm just a newbie in `WinAPI` world.

EDIT:
For those with a similar problem: **Do not do this:**
I made an workaround with global variable ProcessKillFocus set to false indicating that instructions in message management should not be processed, except that at the end (just before break;) I am changing it to true, so next time and later it will be processed:

```
case EN_KILLFOCUS:
           if (ProcessKillFocus && LOWORD(wParam)==MyEditID)
           {
                // first time global ProcessKillFocus is false so all this is skipped
                // 2nd time and later do all the stuff
           }
           ProcessKillFocus = true;
           break;
```

Huge thanx to Sheyros Adikari for making my question easy to understand!!!
Huge thanx to patriiice for simple answer on a huge messing question!!!

**ANSWER:**
BTW: patriiice, I tried this:

```
case WM_INITDIALOG:
        SetFocus(GetDlgItem(hDialog, Desired_Control_ID));
        return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
        break;
```

IT JUST WORKS!!!

Comment: returning before the call to `SetFocus` makes no sense (in your *BTW*) ...

Comment: Ok thanx i see now - just a mistake in an order, you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to return FALSE to [WM_INITDIALOG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message and set the correct focus by yourself.